# Designing single sign on for multiple web sites

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on

I have three websites, that do three separate things, but I would like to implement single sign-on for users to access to all three sites. The sites do not share a db, and two are not in the same domain, also two are php based and one is an ror website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done the same with  Central Authentication Service (http://www.jasig.org/cas) Rails has both CAS server and client

ruby CAS server is here (https://github.com/gunark/rubycas-server)

ruby CAS client is here (http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-client/)

and in theory CAS server and clients can be different languages (Like CAS server is ruby and CAS client is php vise versa...)

and also ruby CAS has a very helpful community through groups

hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 3):

Why not let them use [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/) or a Google ID?  Then they don't have to have a separate login.  Never having implemented it, I don't know any details, but I daresay there's a few around here at SO that have experience with it... I dunno though whether there's licensing involved with using Google ID or not.  There's already enough sites with different logins, why not take this opportunity to save your users having to remember another username and password?  Just my $0.02.

Comment: There is no licensing. There are several libraries you can use to implement it. Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/

Comment: I have heard mixed things on the adoption of openid. I am looking into FB integration but in the end still need an alternative that users can register on my site and go to different properties that may be on different domains.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into http://simplesamlphp.org/ before for true SSO. Got it up and running OK, though I've never used it in production. You can point it to an LDAP directory (like Active Directory), use a local user table or create your own plug in for it. For a working SAML SSO, it's pretty easy to implement (and it's free, which is always nice). SSO in any flavor can be tricky to implement though....  Good luck!